# Android - Huawei Location kit not working - version 'com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.5.300'

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-location-kit

1. After integrating the location kit version 'com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.5.300', location getting as null. Please find attached the apk for testing. you can get the logs from that.
2. In Manifest, I have used the below one.
3. In App gradle, implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.5.300'
4. In Project gradle, classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.300'

**LOGS:**

LBSLog_HwLBSService.PG.c: [E/HwLocation/LBSLog_HwLBSService.PG.c 16710:1474 Method.java:-2] res location is null : {"errorCode":"701200010","message":"all policy locate failed."}
LBSLog_HwLBSService.PG.g: [I/HwLocation/LBSLog_HwLBSService.PG.g 16710:1474 Method.java:-2] status code:512,error code:512

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to Wi-Fi and if GPS signal was weak, then when you move around you get GPS signal and you will be getting a location.

But if you were connected with cellular network for getting GPS that will work at the same position.
It depends on the GPS availability of your position of device.

To solve your problem you need to move away from your current position with device, then you will be able to catch current GPS location.